# Why does the fish shell need to start a daemon process?

Tags: fish

I just started playing with the fish shell, and I really like is so far. 
However, I can't figure out what the purpose of `fishd` is.

So, why does fish need to start up a daemon process?

What is the daemon process used for?

Comment: As of fish 2.2.0 (the most recent version), fishd is no more. fish no longer has any daemon processes and other techniques are used for synchronizing universal variables.

Answer (score 7):

From [fishd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fishd):

> The fishd daemon is used to load, save and distribute universal variable information. fish automatically connects to fishd via a socket on startup. If no instance of fishd is running, fish spawns a new fishd instance. fishd will create a socket in /tmp, and wait for incoming connections from universal variable clients, such as fish, When no clients are connected, fishd will automatically shut down.

Comment: Like what kind of information does it sync.